# Looking inside a diamond film plate at the nanoscale

Tags: diamond

What is the best microscope or other analytical tool for detecting the presence of nano-graphite inside of single crystal diamond film? It would be good to have a 3D map of the nano-graphite, too.

The film size is: 3.0x3.0mm, 0.30mm thick

The graphite could be as small as 10 nm.

Answer (score 0):

For detecting the presence of various phases, use x-ray diffraction.

For a 3D map, you need to image it. So some kind of microscope would be needed. An electron microscope or an atomic force microscope.

Comment: Thank you very much. So, am I correct in thinking that as long as the diamond film is optically clear, an electron microscope or an atomic force microscope will be able to peer down through the top of the film so that it can image any nanographite traces (in the range of 10 nm) that appear within the diamond)?

Comment: No. 10 nm is smaller than optical microscopes can see. Optically clear is irrelevant. An atomic force microscope moves a stylus over the surface and shows surface contours. An electron microscope works something like an optical microscope, but uses electrons. Google for more info. No guarantees that either will do what you want.

Comment: Thanks. Will look at electron crystallography for making a 3D map of the graphite inside of nanodiamond.